# data show from 4 table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to show the common data from all table on base of vendorID where vendorID is unique key in my vendor table. and i use this as an foriegn key for all other(cost table, hour table,employee table, temporary table and ) table.

This is my **Cost table** struructre
[image: cost]
This is my **Hour table** structure
[image: hour]
This is my  **Temporarytable** structure
[image]
This is my **Employee table**
[image: employee table]

This is my Final **table vendor** there are vendorID is unique Key
[image]

And i have use the following query but it is showing the different data.

```
SELECT * FROM cw_employee_csv as emp 
inner join cw_cost_hour as cost on cost.vendorid=emp.vendorid 
inner join cw_temp_employee as temp on cost.vendorid=temp.vendorid 
inner join cw_hour_company as hour on temp.vendorid=hour.vendorid 
inner join cw_vendor as vendor on temp.vendorid=vendor.vendorid 
where vendor.companyid=1 ORDER BY hour.timeFrom ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, try this:

In your query in the field list explicit fields you want to show, for example:

```
SELECT 
    emp.assignmentid, cost.bill_type 
FROM 
    cw_employee_csv AS emp 
INNER JOIN 
    cw_cost_hour AS cost ON cost.vendorid = emp.vendorid 
INNER JOIN 
    cw_temp_employee AS temp ON cost.vendorid = temp.vendorid 
INNER JOIN 
    cw_hour_company AS hour ON temp.vendorid = hour.vendorid 
INNER JOIN 
    cw_vendor AS vendor ON temp.vendorid = vendor.vendorid 
WHERE
    vendor.companyid = 1 
ORDER BY 
    hour.timeFrom ASC
```

If the cardinality of tables is different and you want to show only one row per vendor, you must write a main query with cw_vendor and use some subquery to retrieve additional information by other table. Obviously, about parent table of your vendor table you can use INNER JOIN information without use subqueries.

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

You start by this query (after chat discussion):

I extract an aggregate by company (I suppose to summarize your cost by vendor, if you want to apply another formula, it's the same algorithm)

```
select 
    sum(t.vendor_cost), t.companyid
from 
    (select 
         vendor.companyid as companyid, vendor.id as vendorid,
         (select SUM(c.cost)
          from cw_cost_hoyr c
          where c.vendorid = vendor.id) as vendor_cost
     from 
         cw_vendor vendor) as t
group by 
    t.companyid
```

Now we add other information but I must understand what do you want exactly with their relations

Comment: Actually i need 4 field from the all 4 table for my search employeeid from temp table, amount from employee, cost per hour from cost table and hour from hour table and combination of thies showing me 1995 result whereas i have 108 rows in 1 table,12 in next 2 and 8 in last table. so that there are maximum fild only 108 but it multiply of rows and showing me result

Comment: @vikas tyagi: I try to follow step by step, but, which table has 108 rows? vendors or employee

Comment: My Hour table contain the 108 rows. please here aware also about the company id. when i show report for company there must be need for company id and my company id is only in vendor table or i need it in other table or not

Comment: @vikas tagi: but your output is: employ or vendor?

Comment: hey joy my output is from all the 4 table as i wite above i again paste   Actually i need 4 field from the all 4 table for my search employeeid from temp table, amount from employee, cost per hour from cost table and hour from hour table and combination of thies showing me 1995 result whereas i have 108 rows in 1 table,12 in next 2 and 8 in last table. so that there are maximum fild only 108 but it multiply of rows and showing me result

Comment: @vikas tagi: Yes, but which entity is the aggregation entity? If you don't aggregate, you have 1995 rows (as you don't want...)

Comment: yes exact you have right answer i have got the 1995 result as i also know it multiply the rows. have any way to show exact result. it is confusing the user as well as me to search the data

Comment: @vikas tagi: Ok, to show the exact result we must find the main entity. You want to show 4 fields, aggregate per employ or vendor? Because, if you want per vendor, my start query is the base to further development, instead if you want them per employ I must change my start query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36113/discussion-between-vikas-tyagi-and-joe-taras)